# Power Shell script on USB stick : how to determine drive letter for usb?

Tags: powershell

I want to use a USB stick for storing power shell scripts, scripts I will use on different PCs. Some of these scripts contain paths to the USB stick itself. For instance, if the USB stick is always assigned the drive letter `K:` my script file could contain the following line:

`start notepad K:/my/path/mytext.txt`

for making Power Shell open the file `mytext.txt` on the USB stick, by means of `notepad`.

The problem is that the drive letter assigned for the USB stick changes from PC to PC. How can I use a power script command to find the drive letter assigned to my USB stick?

I imagine this: by the use of `<some command>` I can store the drive letter assigned for my USB stick into a variable `$myvar`

`$myvar = <some command>`

and then use `$myvar` instead of the drive letter in the path I specify. If so, the above script line for opening my text file would look something like this:

`start notepad $myvar/my/path/mytext.txt`

Is this possible, and whats the name and the call to such a command?

Thanks in advance for all helpful suggestions.

Comment: `$PSScriptRoot`

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks for your quick reponse. I tried `start notepad $PSScriptRoot\notes\mytext.txt' but I got the error message `The system cannot find the path specified`. Is `$PSScriptRoot` a predefined variable, or do I have to declare it?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thanks! That made the code function :)

Comment: `[System.Environment]::CurrentDirectory` can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

`(Get-Location).Drive.Name` will give your working directory's drive letter.

However the working directory may not be the script's location.

If you want the script to locate your USB drive and you know your flash drive's label, you can do something like this:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType='2'" |
    ?{$_.Label -eq 'SANDISK 16'}).DriveLetter
```

Replacing "SANDISK 16" with your drives label.